# Encrypting home partition

Tags: ubuntu, ecryptfs

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and have a dedicated drive mounted to */home/USERNAME*.

When I tried `ecrypt-migrate-home -u USERNAME` I got an error the the resource was busy.

I had logged out, stopped all user services, made sure nothing was being accessed with `lsof -n | grep \/home\/`.

I have 2.5x the room on my system drive but */home/USERNAME* is an entire volume.

Should I just `rsync` my user directory to the root drive, encrypt the whole home drive and then remount? As this is not automated I am unsure how to make the correct changes so I can login properly.